Strange error popping up when dowloading the library paho-mqtt-client in Thonny
I've been trying to download the library paho-mqtt-client in thonny for a project but i've been getting this error all the time.
The error says:
Installing to temp directory
Error installing 'paho-mqtt-client': b'403', packages may be partially installed
Installing to: C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpi7yf2ff9\
Warning: micropython.org SSL certificate is not validated

micropip returned with error code 1

I tried deleting folders, closing and opening thonny, even trying in another computers but nowthing seems to work.

The problem is not on your end, the problem was with the micropython.org site that the package is hosted on.
The error states that the SSL certificate was invalid, most likely expired, this appears to have now been fixed by the sites administrators.
